# Pass data to send.php - select option text and value

Tags: javascript, php, forms

Basically i am trying to debug this: Ihave a HTML form and a send.php from which i extract data like

```
 $locridicare= addslashes($_GET['liv']); 
 $locreturnare=addslashes($_GET['ret']); 
 $codlocridicare=addslashes($_GET['locridicare']); 
 $codlocreturnare=addslashes($_GET['locreturnare']);
```

The codlocridicare should get the VALUE and the locridicare should get the TEXT from the SELECT option called locridicare.

Same for codlocreturnare and locreturnare, from the other select.

The form i run:

```
<script>
function changelivrare (objDropDown)
{
document.getElementById("liv").value = objDropDown.value; 
}


function changereturnare (objDropDown)
{
document.getElementById("ret").value = objDropDown.value; 
}
</script>
```

and then the in form

```
<select name="locridicare" id="locridicare" onchange="changelivrare(this)">
<option value=""> --- Selectaţi --- </option>
<option value="3231">Aeroport Otopeni - Bucuresti</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="liv" id="liv" />

<select name="locreturnare" id="locreturnare" onchange="changereturnare(this)" >
<option value=""> --- Selectaţi --- </option>
<option value="3231">Aeroport Otopeni - Bucuresti</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="ret" id="ret" />
```

Comment: Can you add what's in the attributes of <form> i.e. where are you submitting it to?

Comment: You're not putting the text of the selected option into the hidden input, you're putting the value.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

To get the selected option's text, use:

```
function changelivrare(objDropDown) {
    document.getElementById("liv").value = objDropDown.options[objDropDown.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
}
```

`objDropDown.value` is the value of the selected option, not its text. `objDropDown.options` is a collection of the options, and `objDropDown.selectedIndex` is the position of the selected option.

I also suggest you combine the two function into one:

```
function textToHiddenInput(objDropDown, inputID) {
    document.getElementById(inputID).value = objDropDown.options[objDropDown.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
}
```

Then you change the HTML to:

```
<select name="locridicare" id="locridicare" onchange="textToHiddenInput(this, 'liv')">
...
<select name="locreturnare" id="locreturnare" onchange="textToHiddenInput(this, 'ret')" >
```

Comment: What a superb solution. So elegant. I only have one tiny issue. Both fields    $locridicare= addslashes($_GET['liv']); and also        $locreturnare= addslashes($_GET['ret']); return the same value when extracted via SEND.php.  The test page is here https://www.carpro.ro/ping

Comment: Silly me! It works!!!! I lovvvve it. If you ever need some SEO advices or linkbuilding feel free to let me know.